# spring two-way rmi callback from server executing on client side

Tags: java, spring, proxy, callback, rmi

On the server-side I have a `ListenerManager` which fires callbacks to its `Listener`s. The manager is exported using a Spring `RmiServiceExporter`

On the client-side I have a proxy to the manager created by an `RmiProxyFactoryBean`, and a `Listener` implementation registered through this proxy with the manager on the server side.

So far so good: the `ListenerManager` is given a `Listener` and it invokes its callbacks, however since the listener is just a deserialized copy of the client-side object, the callback runs on the server side, not the client side.

How can I get Spring to generate a proxy on the server-side to the client-side listener so that the callback invoked by the server is executed remotely on the client-side? Surely I don't need another (exporter, proxy factory) pair in the opposite direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A **pure RMI solution**: the client-side listener object needs to implement `java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject`. If it does, and each of its methods throw `RemoteException` then when it is passed to the server through the manager proxy everything is wired up automatically, and method invocations on the server-side proxy to this listener are remote invocations of methods on the real client-side object.

This will do, but it's even better to be able to **wrap the object for export without requiring a particular superclass**. We can use a CGLIB Enhancer to "proxy" the listener as a subclass of `UnicastRemoteObject` that also implements the service interfaces. This still requires that the target object implement `java.rmi.Remote` and declare `throws RemoteException`.

Next step is a **solution that can export arbitrary objects** for remote invocation of their methods, without requiring that they implement `Remote` or declare `throws RemoteException`. We must integrate this proxying with the existing Spring infrastructure, which we can do with a new implementation of `RmiBasedExporter` modelled on the non-registry bits of `RmiServiceExporter#prepare()` to export the RMI stub of our proxy and on the invocation part of `RmiClientInterceptor.doInvoke(MethodInvocation, RmiInvocationHandler)`. We need to be able to get hold of an exported proxy instance of our service interfaces. We can model this on the means used by Spring to apparently "export" non-RMI interfaces. Spring proxies the interface to generate a `RmiInvocationWrapper` for invocation of a non-RMI method, serialises the method details and arguments, then invokes this on the far side of the RMI connection.

- Use a `ProxyFactory` and an `RmiInvocationHandler` implementation to proxy the target object.
- Use a new implementation of `RmiBasedExporter` to `getObjectToExport()`, and export it using `UnicastRemoteObject#export(obj, 0)`.
- For the invocation handler, `rmiInvocationHandler.invoke(invocationFactory.createRemoteInvocation(invocation))`, with a `DefaultRemoteInvocationFactory`.
- Handle exceptions and wrap appropriately to avoid seeing `UndeclaredThrowableException`s.

So, we can use RMI to export arbitrary objects. This means we can use one of these objects on the client-side as a parameter to an RMI method call on an RMI server-side object, and when the deserialised stub on the server-side has methods invoked, those methods will execute on the client-side. Magic.

Answer (score 2):

Following Joe Kearney's explaination, I have created my [RMIUtil.java](https://github.com/btpka3/btpka3.github.com/blob/master/java/spring/rmi/first-spring-rmi/src/main/java/me/test/spring/rmi/pojo/RMIUtil.java). Hope there is nothing left.

BTW, please ref [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/645208/java-rmi-nosuchobjectexception-no-such-object-in-table) 
 for "java.rmi.NoSuchObjectException: no such object in table"

Comment: You may want to update your link to RMIUtil.java to [this location](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?source_dir=btpka3.github.com-master/java/spring/rmi/first-spring-rmi/src/main/java/me/test/spring/rmi/pojo/RMIUtil.java)?

Answer (score 0):

Just add some code to Joe's answer.

Extends RmiServiceExporter and get access to exported object:

```
public class RmiServiceExporter extends org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiServiceExporter {
    private Object remoteService;
    private String remoteServiceName;

    @Override
    public Remote getObjectToExport() {
        Remote exportedObject = super.getObjectToExport();

        if (getService() instanceof Remote && (
                getServiceInterface() == null || exportedObject.getClass().isAssignableFrom(getServiceInterface()))) {
            this.remoteService = exportedObject;
        }
        else {
            // RMI Invokers. 
            ProxyFactory factory = new ProxyFactory(getServiceInterface(), 
                    new RmiServiceInterceptor((RmiInvocationHandler) exportedObject, remoteServiceName));

            this.remoteService = factory.getProxy();
        }

        return exportedObject;
    }

    public Object getRemoteService()  {
        return remoteService;
    }

    /** 
     * Override to get access to the serviceName
     */
    @Override
    public void setServiceName(String serviceName) {
        this.remoteServiceName = serviceName;
        super.setServiceName(serviceName);
    }
}
```

The interceptor used in the proxy (the remote service callback):

```
public class RmiServiceInterceptor extends RemoteInvocationBasedAccessor 
    implements MethodInterceptor, Serializable  {

    private RmiInvocationHandler invocationHandler; 
    private String serviceName;

    public RmiServiceInterceptor(RmiInvocationHandler invocationHandler) {
        this(invocationHandler, null);
    }

    public RmiServiceInterceptor(RmiInvocationHandler invocationHandler, String serviceName) {
        this.invocationHandler = invocationHandler;
        this.serviceName = serviceName;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public Object invoke(MethodInvocation invocation) throws Throwable {
        try {
            return invocationHandler.invoke(createRemoteInvocation(invocation));
        }
        catch (RemoteException ex) {
                throw RmiClientInterceptorUtils.convertRmiAccessException(
                    invocation.getMethod(), ex, RmiClientInterceptorUtils.isConnectFailure(ex), 
                    extractServiceUrl());
            }
    }

    /**
     * Try to extract service Url from invationHandler.toString() for exception info
     * @return Service Url
     */
    private String extractServiceUrl() {
        String toParse = invocationHandler.toString();
        String url = "rmi://" + StringUtils.substringBefore(
                StringUtils.substringAfter(toParse, "endpoint:["), "]");

        if (serviceName != null)
            url = StringUtils.substringBefore(url, ":") + "/" + serviceName;

        return url;
    }
}
```

When exporting the service with this `RmiServiceExporter`, we cand send a rmi callback with:

```
someRemoteService.someRemoteMethod(rmiServiceExporter.getRemoteService());
```