# Java: garbage collection for RMI target object?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, rmi

While getting my hands dirty with RMI, I got a `java.rmi.NoSuchObjectException` exception, which led me to this question: [java.rmi.NoSuchObjectException: no such object in table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/645208/java-rmi-nosuchobjectexception-no-such-object-in-table) *but my question is different*.

I'm creating the impl object in my main method and hence in the main thread. If I do this:

```
FooImpl fi = new FooImpl();
foo = (Foo) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(fi, 0);
```

things work fine.

If I do this:

```
foo = (Foo) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(new FooImpl(), 0);
```

I see that FooImpl instance is collected and then I get the aforementioned exception.

`foo` is a static reference that I'm initializng in main; and another remote object returns `foo` from one of its methods. So a client gets that remote object first, then gets `foo` from it, and then calls a method on `foo` and that's when I get the exception as explained above. So why is it happening this way?

EDIT: here's my main method

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws RemoteException, AlreadyBoundException 
{

    Server server = new Server();
    Hello stub = (Hello) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(server, 0);

    FooImpl fi = new FooImpl();
    foo = (Foo) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(fi, 0);

    Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry();
    registry.bind("Hello", stub);       
    System.out.println("Server ready!");        
}
```

In client, I'm getting `hello` and calling a method on it which gives me `foo` and then calling a method on `foo`.

EDIT2: If I use

`Hello stub = (Hello) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(new Server(), 0);`

and bind `foo` first and then `hello`, then same exception is thrown when I try to access `hello` because now it's Server instance which is getting collected. Really weird stuff!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both approaches are liable to fail. There's no real difference between them in terms of variable scoping.

The problem more usually seen in these situations is the Registry itself, when created by `LocateRegistry.createRegistry()`, which you aren't doing. If you were, the created Registry itself can be GC'd too: you must keep the `Registry` reference in a static variable. Then it won't be GC'd, and it will prevent the stub `foo` from being GC'd, and the stub will keep the `FooImpl` from being DGC'd and therefore GC'd.

In your case you would be better off keeping the remote object references (servers, not stubs) in static variables.

Comment: Some additional info: I found out that a call to 'UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject()' is triggering a full gc. Any idea why/how? I tried to look up rmi source code but couldn't find it.

Comment: Well, I see it happening consistently both through Eclipse and command-line. If it's a coincidence, it's a very consistent one. :)